# Are these trees LEGO parts?

Tags: part-identification, 3rd-party

I've come across some trees from some bulk purchases I've made, and I can not determine if these are LEGO or "compatible" parts. Any ideas? The tree on the left is an [official tree](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=3471) but the one in the middle is an odd aqua color, and the one to the right is very similar. Neither the middle nor right trees have any LEGO stamps on them anywhere, which is why I'm pretty sure they are from something "compatible" but figured I'd see if anyone else could identify them. My apologies for the photography.

[image: Three Trees]

Comment: Can you add a bottom view of the trees? The bottom side for LEGO pieces carries Logos or other bits of information helping to confirm their identity.

Comment: I'd have to find them. I asked the question over 9 years ago so I have no idea where they're even at by now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A full list of LEGO tree parts can be found on [Bricklink](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?v=2&pg=1&catString=95&catType=P). I'd encourage anybody looking to identify a brick to use the [part catalogue](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogTree.asp?itemType=P).

The two trees on the right are definitely not LEGO parts.

Comment: So I suppose a meta question might be: Is BrickLink's catalog complete? My understanding is that the answer to that is actually no, though the number of exceptions is pretty small.

Comment: @NathanStohlmann I don't know if it's 100% complete, but it certainly classifies some items under different keys so the list of sets an item appears in doesn't appear accurate.

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid And the question is open-ended enough to not be a good question for this forum I suppose.

Comment: @NathanStohlmann - I'm unsure - we've had a few questions along these lines which were quite successful but since then there's been the [recent blog post "Let's play the guessing game"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/) which seems to imply they aren't great on the network - I'm still curious as to where these trees are from though.

Answer (score 11):

Not sure about the other tree. But the center tree is from Tyco.

Answer (score 1):

The rightmost tree may be a bent original Lego tree. I am not sure as I was not a kid in the 60's or whenever they started coming out with the interlocking stud-type sets.

Answer (score -3):

The first one on the left is definitely LEGO, and the other two are just poor copies.